# W2K8R2 DC: CALS necessary for auth-only users?

Tags: licensing, cals

I'm currently setting up a POC installation of an internally developed web application. We are testing AD auth using the Python LDAP module. My question: does every authenticating web app user need a CAL? Or can we get by with just one device-CAL for the web-app server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> does every authenticating web app user need a CAL?

Yes.

> using the Python LDAP module

Irrelevant. Question is whether you access AD.

> Or can we get by with just one device-CAL for the web-app server?

No.

There is / Was an internet access license that handles all external authentication for (HIGH) flat sum.

Someone obviously did not do any home work when planning this. Now is the time the invoice comes.